# Snippet of code that is not reading file as expected?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Here I have a work-in-progress file reading utility of sorts that I'm attempting to use to load different configurations of bullet-firing configurations (in-game objects) from a file.

```
package game.entity.bullet;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector2f;

public class ConfigReader {

    public static List<BulletConfiguration> configurations = new ArrayList<BulletConfiguration>();

    public void loadConfigs(String input) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(input);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("START:")) {
                BulletConfiguration b = new BulletConfiguration();
                String name = line.split(": ")[1];
                b.name = name;
                while (!line.startsWith("END:")) {
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    String bt = line.split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
                    Vector2f bulletPos = new Vector2f(
                            Float.parseFloat(line.split(" ")[2].split(":")[0]),
                            Float.parseFloat(line.split(" ")[2].split(":")[1]));
                    Vector2f bulletVelocity = new Vector2f(
                            Float.parseFloat(line.split(" ")[3].split(":")[0]),
                            Float.parseFloat(line.split(" ")[3].split(":")[1]));
                    b.bullets.add(BulletType.valueOf(bt));
                    b.bullet_spawn_positions.add(bulletPos);
                    b.bullet_velocities.add(bulletVelocity);
                }
                configurations.add(b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A couple sample configurations are here for examples:

```
BEGIN: Cannon
p Standard 0:0 0:1
END:

BEGIN: Triple Cannon
p Small 0:0 -0.25:1
p Small 0:0 0:1
p Small 0:0 0.25:1
END:
```

That's really all that I have to help explain what I'm trying to do.  It's supposed to check when the "BEGIN:" is stated, and then go through until it hits the "END:" statement, and to parse the values into their respective values.

Also, give me a little bit of feedback on my question; it's my first one, so I'm not sure if this is totally acceptable.

Comment: If you're suppose to looking for `BEGIN:` why are using `line.startsWith("START:")`?

Comment: What are you looking for and how this program fails?

Answer (score 1):

Change your while loop in following way:

```
line = reader.readLine();

    while (!line.startsWith("END:")) {
        String bt = line.split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
        Vector2f bulletPos = new Vector2f(
                Float.parseFloat(line.split(" ")[2].split(":")[0]),
                Float.parseFloat(line.split(" ")[2].split(":")[1]));
        Vector2f bulletVelocity = new Vector2f(
                Float.parseFloat(line.split(" ")[3].split(":")[0]),
                Float.parseFloat(line.split(" ")[3].split(":")[1]));
        b.bullets.add(BulletType.valueOf(bt));
        b.bullet_spawn_positions.add(bulletPos);
        b.bullet_velocities.add(bulletVelocity);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
```

And as pointed out by @MadProgrammer change

```
if (line.startsWith("START:"))
```

to

```
if (line.startsWith("BEGIN:"))
```